# Clean URLS not working on server.

Tags: php, .htaccess

Firstly I apologize if this is slightly broad of a question. I hope it is not.

On my localhost I have this htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/?$ http://myasite.com/region.php?reg=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2})/(.*?)/(\d+)$ http://myasite.com/single-id.php?reg=$1&n=$3&area=$2 [L,QSA]
```

When I go to:

> http://myasite.com/uk

I am redirected to:

> http://myasite.com/region.php?reg=$1

However the URL stays the same as:

> http://myasite.com/uk

Which is PERFECT. However, when I upload that to my site server the url does not retain the clean url.

I have asked the server support guys and on the live chat to which I am convinced they nothing about it. I kept getting the response from them 'The problem is the htaccess, contact a developer'

My server has ControlPanel/WHM

Does anyone know why the clean URLS are not working on the server but they are on my localhost and could someone provide steps to help check/fix this issue?

Comment: May not do anything, but try setting the `RewriteBase /` just under `RewriteEngine On`.

Comment: nope nothing different

Comment: @Darren did you just delete your comment? It worked anyway :)

Comment: @Darren if you put it as answer I will accept it

Comment: I thought it might error out haha that's why I deleted it, but I've posted the answer. Glad it helped!

Comment: You are getting an external redirection because of the full target url. Remove the http and hostname from your rewrite target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be something to do with your `RewriteRule`, so modify it to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ region.php?reg=$1 [QSA,L]
```

<sup>*Might also be worth replacing `+` with the exact character count you may encounter for each region, i.e. `{2}` :-) - [**Example**](http://regexr.com/3f6k5)*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Please echo $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']; just in case the server is not running the php file on nginx server. I have seen this one time.

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'];
?>
```

Comment: > Apache is the result

Comment: Try this 

`Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://myasite.com/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)/?$ http://myasite.com/region.php?reg=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]{2})/(.*?)/(\d+)$ http://myasite.com/single-id.php?reg=$1&n=$3&area=$2 [L,QSA]`